# Cannot call to a public function of Model (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, function

I just started learning Laravel, I'm newbie. I've got a problem, I'm watching Laravel Course for beginners and learning, was doing exactly the same as in he tutorial, but still ended up with a problem. I hope to find a solution soon. I'll explain it a little bit.
The project is kind of a clone of Instagram. Users can post images to page.

I have this function in User model

**User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

And I'm trying to access it from my PostsController

**PostsController.php**

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image']
        ]);

        auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

        \App\Models\Post::create($data);

        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

I'm doing exactly as in tutorial, but for some reason this line is failing at `posts()` call.

`auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);`

I'm getting that it's undefined method. But it is indeed defined in User.php

EDIT:

Exact error I'm getting is:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.user_id (SQL: insert into "posts" ("caption", "image", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Caption, C:\xampp\tmp\php2E32.tmp, 2021-05-19 12:16:08, 2021-05-19 12:16:08))

And foreign key is `user_id`.
Actually I just checked my posts table and it seems it is stored in database, so it's working, but how to get rid of this error then?

Comment: what is your foreign key in post table?? and what is the exact error you are getting??

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with Laravel but with the constraints in your database table.  To know these, we would need to see the respective migration file

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? And how is this related to [tag:authentication] or [tag:function]?

Comment: @NicoHaase Well that's because as I mentioned, my VSCode shows undefined method 'posts()' in this line `auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);` and I think that's why I get error

Comment: As VSCode does not execute the code, it might not know where `posts()` is defined. So, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not put `auth()->user()` into a variable first to check what it contains? Please don't guess or explain what the code does, **debug** it properly by either using `var_dump` (or equivalents) or running XDebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a silly mistake of you..you are adding same post twice. once with relationship association and again from post model.

```
auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

\App\Models\Post::create($data); //this is causing the issue here.
```

with relationship association `auth()->user()->posts()->create($data)`, post is inserted to the database. as the foreign key `user_id` is coming from relationship. but in the next line `\App\Models\Post::create($data)`, your `$data` array is missing `user_id` and thus the NOT NULL constraint failed error occurs. you can't insert a row with `user_id` being null. and this line is actually adding duplicate data. remove this line. use either one of the method.

with relationship association

```
$data = request()->validate([
    'caption' => 'required',
    'image' => ['required', 'image']
]);

auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
```

or using model directly

```
$data = request()->validate([
    'caption' => 'required',
    'image' => ['required', 'image']
]);

$data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id; //added user_id in the validated data array    
\App\Models\Post::create($data);
```

and vs code always don't know all of your functions. depending on vs code to find a problem is not the best way.

Comment: I feel so stupid now... That was the only problem, exactly as you explained. Thank you for help! Sorry for my such silly mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

Note:: you need to use Post Model and you can directly create data Using Post::create() method.

```
//Import Data
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Modes\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
     public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Check Validation 
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image']
        ]);

       //Get Login User Data in $user variable
        $user = auth()->user();

       //Store user id into $data variable which we can pass into $data Variable.
        $data[‘user_id’] = $user->id;

        //Create Data Using create() method.
        $post = Post::create($data);
        
       //Final Save Your Data
        if( $post->save() ) {
    dd(“data save successfully”);
       }else{
    dd(“something went wrong”);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it